# Java RMI, making an object serializeable AND remote

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

You might be thinking why would you want to have an object both Remote AND serializeable. Well let me give you some context.

I'm building an air traffic control system (school project), it's distributed so that each control zone runs on it's own server and communicates with other control zones. Each control zone keeps track of its own aiplanes.

When an airplane (flying in controlzone A) is 100km near its border, it is passed as a remote object to the controlzone (controlzone B) it's near to. This way controlzone B can see where the aiplane is (by periodical asking its position) while it's still controlled by controlzone A.

But when an airplane crosses the border between controlzone A and B, controlzone B should keep track of the airplane instead of controlzone A. So we we want to serialize the airplane and pass it to controlZone B. This is where our problem lies.

Can I make the airplane remote AND serializeable?

EDIT: Also, I could use remote methods to copy the needed fields for the airplane, but I prefer serializing it.

Comment: If the Airplane is Serializable, why not just pass it to Controlzone X at a certain distance away from it, I don't see the need for it to be Remote also

Comment: I need it's position 20 times a second and I don't want to ask Controlzone A 20 times for the serialized object..

Comment: The question would be, how should the RMI system decide when to serialize the object (i.e. copy it) and when to pass it as a remote reference?

Comment: you could ask for it once from ControlZone A, then both A & B can track its movement until it crosses fully into B.

Comment: That won't work because the airplane is controlled by A when it's in zone A. So if I just leave the copy @ B it won't move or change directions when given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a remote object isn't exported at the time it is sent as a remote method parameter or result, it is serialized instead of being passed as a remote reference, provided that it implements Serializable as well as Remote. It is then exported at the receiver. UnicastRemoteObject does this for example, and therefore so does any remote object derived from it. This can be used for mobile remote agents.

Comment: well, considering that the Airplane instance will most likely _be_ exported at the time it needs to be Serialized and sent remote, i would imagine my solution would be necessary.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Or if not, not. This isn't getting us anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to make your object subclass UnicastRemoteObject.

Take your class, define it to implement Serializable and your RMI api interface, which itself should implement Remote.  It doesn't need to subclass anything other than java.lang.Object.

When you are ready for your object to be called remotely, call the static UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject() method on it.  From that point on, any reference you return over RMI to that object will be remotely callable.

When you want to pass the object off to another server, call UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject() on your object.  Then when you pass it over an RMI call, you'll be passing the serialized representation of that object.

The downside to this is once you pass it off, the object on your server will no longer accept RMI calls.  unexportObject() turns it off completely as an RMI call recipient.

If you want to be able to maintain an object as an RMI target and concurrently pass it around over RMI as a serializable object, you'll need to make it serializable and interpose a proxy object that exports the Remote interface and which can talk to the non-exported, serializable object on the caller's behalf.

When you want to pass the underlying object with serialization, you pass it directly.  When you want to pass a remotely callable reference to it, you pass the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `UnicastRemoteObject` class. It is normally used for callback driven programming in RMI and hence implements both `Remote` and `Serializable`. Though you might want to revisit your logic since you now have an entity (airplane) which acts like a "remote server".

Comment: Not really, could you tell why you think it acts like a remote server?

Comment: Please read the docs for `UnicastRemoteObject` and specifically its superclass `RemoteServer` for more explanation. This class is normally used when you want to export an "object" from a JVM and all changes/method invocations on this unicast object affect the original object rather than affecting the copy which is what normally happens when your objects are serializable but not remote.

Comment: I know this, as my OP states I want this behaviour at first. But when the airplane crosses I want it to pass a copy instead of a remote obj

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this solution was not correct.  See @EJP's answer below for the only way to do this with a single instance.

Comment: Not extending UnicastRemoteObject doesn't actually have anything to do with it. See my answer.

Comment: @EJP - not extending UnicastRemoteObject certainly _does_ has something to do with.  while it can be apparently made to "sort of" work when you _do_ extend UnicastRemoteObject (i didn't know that), i think my solution is much cleaner.

Comment: @jtahborn No. If you extend UnicastRemoteObject you get 'implements Serializable' free. If you don't you can add it yourself. There is no other difference.

Comment: @EJP - i'm not sure what your argument is at this point.  basically, if you _don't_ extend UnicastRemoteObject, you get very clear semantics for both serialization and exporting.  if you _do_ extend it, the serialization semantics are dependent on the current export status, which, to me, is kind of ugly.

Comment: @jtahlborn My 'argument' is that your sentence commencing 'The trick is ...' is irrelevant. You get Serializable if you do extend UnicastRemoteObject, and you can add it yourself if you don't. There is no 'trick' to it.

Comment: @EJP - okay, i think i understand your argument now.  however, that is orthogonal to the question.  maybe the title should be re-phrased "how can i make an object Serializable and Remote and be easily remotable and serializable".  in which case, the answer "simply extend UnicastRemoteObject" is not sufficient, as it does not allow one to serialize a currently exported object.  my solution does, which is why it was accepted.

Comment: @jtahlborn *Nothing* allows you to serialize an already exported object via RMI. The only 'trick' is that the object has to be non-exported at the moment it is passed as an RMI parameter or returned as an RMI result. Extending/not extending UnicastRemoteObject has nothing to do with that except that it exports the object on construction. You can undo that and redo that yourself just as you can if you didn't extend it. Answers being accepted aren't a valid measure of their accuracy: only the OP can do that, and he doesn't *know* the answer, otherwise he wouldn't be posting at all.

Comment: @EJP - so, you are saying this will not work?  that if the airplane instance has been exported in the manner i described, that i cannot also serialize that same airplane instance (i'll only get the stub)?